# DocuSign: Error Description: Could not find a DocuSign User entity for the current user - transaction creation failed

Tags: docusignapi, dynamics-crm-2016

I am using a DocuSign Custom Workflow and the DocuSign API. I am always getting an error,  **Error Description: Could not find a DocuSign User entity for the current user - transaction creation failed**. I have tried many ways like refreshing the configuration connection to O365 and assigning the users with the DocuSign User Role. Still we're getting this error. Any idea why?

Here is the screenshot of the DocuSign Workflow.

[image: DocuSignWorkflowOOB]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because somehow, the association between your CRM user and your DocuSign user got deleted or removed.  Try going to a DocuSign enabled entity and clicking "Go To DocuSign" from it ("..." button in the ribbon).  That should re-establish the association between CRM and DocuSign.  Workflows don't do this automatically for you.

If that does not work, you should get in contact with our customer support because we have a newer version out (4.2) which will allow you to edit the associations between CRM users and DocuSign users.